# TypeError: jsdom.createVirtualConsole is not a function

Tags: node.js, scala, npm, scala.js

I am trying to build upon the [basic Scala.js tutorial](https://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/) and am having this weird error.

There isn't much different from the project set-up as shown in the tutorial, but just in case here's my build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

name := "algorithms1_4_34"
version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.12" % "3.0.1" % "test",
            "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.13.4" % "test",
             "org.scala-js" % "scalajs-dom_sjs0.6_2.12" % "0.9.1",
             "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.1")

// This is an application with a main method
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true

skip in packageJSDependencies := false
jsDependencies +=
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4" / "2.1.4/jquery.js"
jsDependencies += RuntimeDOM
```

...and the JSApp file:

```
package ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms1_4_34

import scala.scalajs.js.JSApp
import org.scalajs.jquery.jQuery

object HotAndColdJS extends JSApp{

   def main(): Unit = {
     jQuery(()=>setupUI())
  }

  def addClickedMessage():Unit ={
    jQuery("body").append("<p>You clicked the button!</p>")
  }

  def setupUI():Unit = {
    //click envokes an event handler
    jQuery("#click-me-button").click(()=> addClickedMessage())
    jQuery("body").append("<p>Hello World!</p>")
  }
}
```

I can run `compile`, `fastOptJS`, `reload` and `eclipse` (I am using eclipsePlugin) commands without problems. The only issue is the `run` command. To be fair I did add something to the flow of the tutorial, but only because running this command (`npm install jsdom`) from the root of application lead to failure in `run` as well (`npm WARN enoent ENOENT`). Following this as advised [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/261) I ran:

```
npm init
npm install
npm install jsdom
```

And this is where I am now. This is the error I get when running the app with `run`:

```
> run
[info] Running ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms1_4_34.HotAndColdJS
[error] [stdin]:40
[error]     virtualConsole: jsdom.createVirtualConsole().sendTo(console),
[error]                           ^
[error] 
[error] TypeError: jsdom.createVirtualConsole is not a function
[error]     at [stdin]:40:27
[error]     at [stdin]:61:3
[error]     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
[error]     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:38)
[error]     at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)
[error]     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
[error]     at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:391:27)
[error]     at Socket.<anonymous> (bootstrap_node.js:188:13)
[error]     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
[error]     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: Node.js with JSDOM exited with code 1
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$AbstractExtRunner.waitForVM(ExternalJSEnv.scala:107)
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$ExtRunner.run(ExternalJSEnv.scala:156)
    at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$.org$scalajs$sbtplugin$ScalaJSPluginInternal$$jsRun(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:697)
    at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$73$$anonfun$apply$48$$anonfun$apply$49.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:814)
    at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$73$$anonfun$apply$48$$anonfun$apply$49.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:808)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: Node.js with JSDOM exited with code 1
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 23-May-2017 9:24:20 PM
```

I would appreciate if anyone could give me a hand with this.

Comment: What Scala.js version do you use? Since jsdom v10 was released, Scala.js 0.6.16 is required. Older versions cannot work with jsdom v10.

Comment: Thank you. That might be it. Mine is Scala.js 0.6.15. There's no way to install an older version of jsdom?

Comment: I upgraded Scala.js to 0.6.16 and it worked. Thanks @sjrd If you wish you may copy your comment to an answer and I will be happy to mark it as correct. May be it will help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsdom v10 introduced some breaking changes wrt. v9, and Scala.js <= 0.6.15 was not prepared for those. That is what's causing the error you're hitting.

Upgrading to Scala.js 0.6.16 will fix your issue. It supports both jsdom v9 and v10.

Comment: The current version jsdom v12 is only supported by Scala.js 0.6.25